# Why does the keyboard not show in my UITextView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview

I have a container class which is a view controller.
It holds the UITextView for notes and has another view controller as a subview, called it PDFViewController. That one has an array of view controllers, called them PageViewController's, in it and a UIScrollView so i can swipe through the different view controllers from the array.

Each of the PageViewController's has also an UIScrollView, so i can zoom the different pages.

But when I show my UITextView i cannot edit or write anything.
It shows a blinking cursor, but no keyboard and can't write text.
When i highlight a word from the default text, it shows me some dictionary options but the words won't be replaced.

I just don't know where the problem might be.

**container.m (View Controller)**

```
- (void) initNotes {

notesVisible = FALSE;
notes = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, note_width, note_height)];
notes.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
notes.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:24];  
notes.text = @"Hier ist Platz für Ihre Notizen";

container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(start_x, start_y, container_width, container_height)];
container.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[container.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[container.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 3.0)];
[container.layer setShadowOpacity:0.6];
[container.layer setShadowRadius:5];
container.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
[container addSubview:notes];
[self.view addSubview:container];
}

- (void) showTextView {
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveAndStrech" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

container.frame = CGRectMake(start_x, self.view.center.y-container_height, container_width, container_height); 

[UIView commitAnimations];

notesVisible = !notesVisible;
}

- (void) hideTextView {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveAndStrech" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

container.frame = CGRectMake(start_x, start_y, container_width, container_height); 

// [notes resignFirstResponder];
[UIView commitAnimations];

notesVisible = !notesVisible;
}
```

@implementation PDFViewController

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
painting = false;
dataInstance = [PDFDataInstance sharedInstance];
chapter = [dataInstance chapter];
[self getNumberOfPages];
kNumberOfPages = dataInstance.pages;

// Register observer to be called when a cell from BookmarkPDFController is pressed
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(didSelectBookmark:) 
                                             name:@"bookmarkPressedinPDFView" object:nil];
// Register observer to be called when a cell from BookmarkPDFController is pressed
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(togglePainting:) 
                                             name:@"togglePainting" object:nil];

    // view controllers are created lazily
// in the meantime, load the array with placeholders which will be replaced on demand
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++)
{
    [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
self.viewControllers = controllers;
[controllers release];

// a page is the width of the scroll view
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;

currentPage = [[chapter currentPage] integerValue];


// pages are created on demand
// load the visible page
// load the page on either side to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling
// 
// Load pages based on currentPage cause of when coming from bookmarks
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:currentPage];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:currentPage+1];

// update the scroll view to the appropriate page
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * currentPage;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];


}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page
{
if (page < 0)
    return;
if (page >= kNumberOfPages)
    return;

// replace the placeholder if necessary
PageViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
{
    //page+1 cause CGPDF indexing starts with 1
    controller = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPageNumberAndUrl:page+1: [chapter urlOnFilesystem]];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    [controller release];
}

// add the controller's view to the scroll view
if (controller.view.superview == nil)
{
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;

    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

}
}
```

**TextView delegates**

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

NSLog(@"begin editing");
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString*)aText
{
NSLog(@"something changed"); 
return YES; 
}
```

Comment: add notes.delegate=self in init;

Comment: It's strange, in my table view, first view in my navigation controller, it works. But when i open the PDF Controller it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the scroll views. Maybe the text view doesn't receive the touches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the UITextView receiving touches? Implement the UITextViewDelegate methods and see if they get called (esp **textViewDidBeginEditing:** and **textView: shouldChangeTextInRange: replacementText:**). This way you'll know for sure whether the text view is indeed handling the touches or not.

If it does, then I don't see anything wrong with your code (except you might have accidentally added a view overlapping the textview)

Comment: If didBeginEditing is called that means the textview is detecting your tap (unless you make it first responder from code). And if it is detecting taps, the text should change as well (unless you have made it non-editable). I am also a little confused by your view's structure!

Answer (score 58):

Just want to add another possibility here. In the iOS simulator, make sure the "Hardware/Keyboard/Connect Hardware Keyboard" is not checked. It took me a couple of hours to figure out this. I guess I toggled that option by accidently pressing the shortcut. Not good experience :(

[image: Menus]

As pictured, Connect Hardware Keyboard should be UN-checked.

Comment: It's always the small things that causes the biggest issues. An hour wasted due to forgetting I had that turned on.

Comment: Ugh. Also wasted an hour on this; running the Xcode 6 DP and had the same problem, don't remember this ever happening in Xcode <= 5.

Comment: don't know how it went on, but upgrading to xcode 6 did this auto-un-magically.

Comment: Keyboard shortcut is Command+Shift+K. Same as Clean in Xcode. :D

Comment: Have literally have wasted 3 hours trying to work out why the normal keyboard doesn't appear when switching from a custom inputView... The ability to hide the software keyboard in the Simulator is so dumb. Causes more harm than good.

Comment: That was it in my case. THANK YOU!!!! Spent hours in code :)

Answer (score 4):

No one asked , but have you set :

```
notes.editable = YES ;
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in the delegate of your textview. Following method is returning YES.

`- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
  return YES;
}`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

After you have set the notes delegates, do the following.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([textView isEqual:notes]) {
        NSLog(@"notes begin editing");
    }
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString*)aText {
    if ([aTextView isEqual:notes]) {
        NSLog(@"something changed in notes");
    }

    return YES; 
}
```

This should confirm delegates of notes are indeed getting called.

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement your container class with UITextViewDelegate 
and add notes.delegate=self; just after initialize the notes object in initNotes method.

Answer (score 1):

Check for 2 things:

1. Is notes.editable = YES; if so please change it to NO.

2.Check whether your UITextView delegates are called are not. If not Please make sure you include  in your implementation file and set notes.delegate = self.

Comment: Now I don't have a blinking cursor. Which UITextView delegates should be called?

Comment: Make sure these delegates textViewDidBeginEditing and textView shouldChangeTextInRange called when you click inside TextView

Comment: notes.editable should be set to YES for the delegate methods to be called. He wants to be able to edit the textiview, not make it non-editable!

Comment: @lost Yes, that's right. beginEditing is called, i said that before.

Answer (score 1):

Try without `container`, just use the UITextView (`notes`) as the container itself.
Every time you used container use notes instead.

And then dont:

```
[container addSubview:notes];
[self.view addSubview:container];
```

Just:

```
[self.view addSubview:notes];
```

Tell me how it goes

Answer (score 1):

I had similar behavior, the `UITextView` not responding to touches and the keyboard not showing.

My `UITextView` was layered on top of a `UICollectionView` which was receiving all the touches even though the `UITextView` was visibly on top.

I fixed it by adjusting the frame of the `UICollectionView` so that the `UITextView` has nothing behind it.  After that, all the delegate methods were called like a charm.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

please Refer this one. where ContantView is your view/textfield and _bubbletable is your table.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
 {
 NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
 CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

    CGRect frame = _ContantView.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= kbSize.height;
    _ContantView.frame = frame;

    frame = _bubbleTable.frame;
    frame.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    _bubbleTable.frame = frame;

}];
```

}